# Objective C wait until an asynch task has been processed

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

In my code, I am running a local server (CocoaHTTPServer). When the server receives a request, it creates a thread and passes control to a certain method ( - `(NSObject<HTTPResponse> *)httpResponseForMethod:(NSString *)method URI:(NSString *)path`, perhaps irrelevant here).

I need to read a list of local assets and return the result. The API call ( `[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) ...` ) is asynchronous.

Since the HTTPResponse needs to wait until the API call has finished, I have created a flag called `_isProcessing` , which I set before making the API call. After the call is finished, I am unsetting the flag and returning the HTTP request. The code to wait looks like:

```
// the API call is non-blocking. hence, wait in a loop until the command has finished
samCommand->isProcessing = YES;
while (samCommand->isProcessing) {
    usleep(100*1000);
}
```

The API call calls a delegate method upon finishing its task as follows:

```
// to be called at the end of an asynch operation (eg: reading local asset list)
- (void) commandDidFinish {
    // flag to open the lock
    isProcessing = NO;
}
```

This works, but will perhaps require performance enhancements. How can I use anything (run-loop etc) here to improve upon the performance.

---

### Edit following weichsel solution using dispatch_semaphore

Following weichsel's solution, I created a semaphore. The sequence of my code is:

1. CocoaHTTPServer receives a request and hence creates a new thread
2. It calls the static method of a Command class to execute the request
3. The Command class creates a new command Object calls another class (using reflection) which calls ALAsset APIs and passes the command Object to it
4. Upon returning, the ALAsset API call calls the delegate method of
   the command class

I have hence embedded semaphores in appropriate locations. However, the semaphore's wait loop just doesnt end sometimes. The normal output should be:

```
2014-02-07 11:27:23:214 MM2Beta[7306:1103] HTTPServer: Started HTTP server on port 1978
2014-02-07 11:27:23:887 MM2Beta[7306:6303] created semaphore 0x1f890670->0x1f8950a0
2014-02-07 11:27:23:887 MM2Beta[7306:6303] calling execute with 0x1f890670
2014-02-07 11:27:23:887 MM2Beta[7306:6303] starting wait loop 0x1f890670->0x1f8950a0
2014-02-07 11:27:23:887 MM2Beta[7306:907] calling getAssetsList with delegate 0x1f890670
2014-02-07 11:27:24:108 MM2Beta[7306:907] calling delegate [0x1f890670 commandDidFinish]
2014-02-07 11:27:24:108 MM2Beta[7306:907] releasing semaphore 0x1f890670->0x1f8950a0
2014-02-07 11:27:24:109 MM2Beta[7306:6303] ending wait loop 0x1f890670->0x0
```

In every few runs, the last step ( `ending wait loop 0x1f890670->0x0` doesnt occur). Hence, the wait loop never ends. Sometimes the code crashes too, exactly at the same point. Any clue what is wrong here.

My code is as follows:

```
    @implementation SAMCommand {
    NSData* resultData;
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore; // a lock to establish whether the command has been processed
}

// construct the object, ensuring that the "command" field is present in the jsonString
+(NSData*) createAndExecuteCommandWithJSONParamsAs:(NSString *)jsonString {

    SAMCommand* samCommand = [[SAMCommand alloc] init];

    samCommand.commandParams = [jsonString dictionaryFromJSON];

    if(COMPONENT==nil || COMMAND==nil){
        DDLogError(@"command not found in %@",jsonString);
        return nil;
    }

    samCommand->semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    DDLogInfo(@"created semaphore %p->%p",samCommand,samCommand->semaphore);

    // to execute a command contained in the jsonString, we use reflection. 
    DDLogInfo(@"calling execute with %p",samCommand);
    [NSClassFromString(COMPONENT) performSelectorOnMainThread:NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@_%@:",COMMAND,MEDIA_SOURCE,MEDIA_TYPE]) withObject:samCommand waitUntilDone:NO];

    // the above calls are non-blocking. hence, wait in a loop until the command has finished
    DDLogInfo(@"starting wait loop %p->%p",samCommand,samCommand->semaphore);
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(samCommand->semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    DDLogInfo(@"ending wait loop %p->%p",samCommand,samCommand->semaphore);
    DDLogInfo(@"");

    // return the data
    return samCommand->resultData;

}

// to be called at the end of an asynch operation (eg: reading local asset list)
- (void) commandDidFinish {

    // flag to release the lock
    DDLogInfo(@"releasing semaphore %p->%p",self,semaphore);
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    semaphore = nil;

}

@end
```

**I got it to work :)**

Finally, what seems to work stably is creating the semaphore, and passing it to the ALAsset asynch API calls, and releasing it at the end of the call. Earlier, I was calling a delegate method of the class where I had created the semaphore, and the semaphore object was somehow getting releases. Unsure of what was happening there really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use semaphore to block execution of the current queue until another one returns.
The basic pattern is:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[assetsLibrary enumerateAssetsUsingBlock^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop):^{
    ...
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(semaphore);
```

You can find a full example of this method in Apple's MTAudioProcessingTap Xcode Project:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AudioTapProcessor
The relevant lines start at MYViewController.m:86

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used your solution, and got things to work partly. Kindly see my edit and see if you can spot the bug.

Answer (score 0):

NSRunLoop has a method called runUntilDate: which should work for you with dates in near future like 1s ahead or so. That way you can replace your sleep call in the while loop for example with:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeintervalSinveNow:1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So in principle, what is the difference between a usleep() and your approach? Arent both of them are creating a wait loop which is polling the given amount of time ... 100 ms in this case? Then where does the performance enhancement come from?

Comment: sleep does block the runLoop from processing. My approach won't do that. With GUI apps you would see the spinning wait cursor when calling sleep.